# hexadecimal dump to binary - xxd -r equivalent

Tags: ruby, hexdump

In Linux bash shell, I use the following to convert a plain hexadecimal dump into binary

```
$ echo "8cd59ef53c9aaa68311b73767e0975e7" | xxd -r -p > xxd_out.bin
```

when I open the file in text viewer it looks like `ŒÕžõ<šªh1sv~ uç`

or in xxd

```
$ xxd -b xxd_out.bin
00000000: 10001100 11010101 10011110 11110101 00111100 10011010  ....<.
00000006: 10101010 01101000 00110001 00011011 01110011 01110110  .h1.sv
0000000c: 01111110 00001001 01110101 11100111                    ~.u.
```

or in Notepad++ Hex-Editor (plugin) view
[image]

How can I get the same binary output in Ruby ? Is there any library available which does what `xxd -r -p` would do ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use [Array#pack](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Array.html#method-i-pack)

`.scan(/../)` will split `"8cd59e"` into `["8c","d5","9e"]`

`.map(&:hex)` will convert it to `[0x8c, 0xd5, 0x9e]`

`.pack("c*")` will pack it to `"\x8c\xd5\x9e"`

```
echo "8cd59ef53c9aaa68311b73767e0975e7" | \
  ruby -ne 'print $_.scan(/../).map(&:hex).pack("c*")' | \
  xxd -b
```

output:

```
00000000: 10001100 11010101 10011110 11110101 00111100 10011010  ....<.
00000006: 10101010 01101000 00110001 00011011 01110011 01110110  .h1.sv
0000000c: 01111110 00001001 01110101 11100111                    ~.u.
```

Comment: or [my_hex_string].pack('H*')