# How to obtain value of "x5t" using Certificate credentials for application authentication

Tags: azure, certificate, azure-active-directory, azure-authentication

I was trying to obtain JWT token from Microsoft Azure Active Directory using [Certificate credentials for application authentication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-certificate-credentials).

I am struck at figuring out the value of "x5t".

I have tried with

- SHA-1 fingerprint value available in the public certificate.
- SHA-1 hash of the public certificate using FVIC.

But i keep getting below error when send the request to MSA login endpoint

```
{
    "error": "invalid_client",
    "error_description": "AADSTS70002: Error validating credentials. AADSTS50012: Client assertion contains an invalid signature. [Reason - The key was not found., Thumbprint of key used by client: '6F67F76B96F6FBBDF9D3EE1DDF7F9A7B877EE9C75DEDBD3DE9C7FB', Configured keys: [Key0:Start=06/01/2018, End=12/31/2099, Thumbprint=6WGktXA64QmA9TPv;Key1:Start=06/01/2018, End=12/31/2099, Thumbprint=rD9Q10sR6Q6ZkDVw;]]\r\nTrace ID: d9e3e276-e878-4b8a-b08b-10c82a0b0600\r\nCorrelation ID: 48ec889d-2376-45a6-9bf0-01b22b0e0c17\r\nTimestamp: 2018-06-01 09:38:24Z",
    "error_codes": [
        70002,
        50012
    ],
    "timestamp": "2018-06-01 09:38:24Z",
    "trace_id": "d9e3e276-e878-4b8a-b08b-10c82a0b0600",
    "correlation_id": "48ec889d-2376-45a6-9bf0-01b22b0e0c17"
}
```

How to obtain the value for "x5t" ?

Answer (score 17):

I found this [site](https://stelfox.net/blog/2014/04/calculating-rsa-key-fingerprints-in-ruby/) and this [one](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/arsen/2015/09/18/certificate-based-auth-with-azure-service-principals-from-linux-command-line/) invaluable for solving the x5t issue. The easiest way to do it is to manually get the fingerprint:

```
echo $(openssl x509 -in your.cert.pem -fingerprint -noout) | sed 's/SHA1 Fingerprint=//g' | sed 's/://g' | xxd -r -ps | base64
```

the value from the above command is the value you put in the x5t field in the JWT. Prior to that I was getting invalid fingerprint error from azure.

If you're using Ruby you can follow this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42262046/hexadecimal-dump-to-binary-xxd-r-equivalent) to get:

```
p12 = OpenSSL::PKCS12.new(File.read(CERT_FILE), '')
x509_sha1_thumbprint = Base64.encode64(OpenSSL::Digest::SHA1.new(p12.certificate.to_der).digest).strip
jwt_token = JWT.encode payload, p12.key, 'RS256', { typ: 'JWT', x5t: x509_sha1_thumbprint }
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. On my Mac+Chrome, the _scroll bar_ is kind of annoying when I want to read the (first) command (where you retrieve the fingerprint). I cannot read properly because when I scroll the _scroll bar_ stays. Assuming a lot of Mac+Chrome users encounter the same problem, I'd say editing it somehow (i.e. with a new line after the command) would improve readability.

Comment: on my Mac+Chrome it scrolls ok

Comment: What do you consider „ok“? Because the scroll is fine, it’s the bar that is positioned quite bad :)

Comment: I used this approach and it worked. You saved me quite some work @codebrane!

Comment: There's a slightly simpler way to generate the digest without parsing hex: `OpenSSL::Digest::SHA1.new(p12.certificate.to_der).digest`

Answer (score 2):

The `x5t` should be the X509 certificate's SHA-1 thumbprint, base64url-encoded:

> **4.1.7.  "x5t" (X.509 Certificate SHA-1 Thumbprint) Header Parameter**

> The "x5t" (X.509 certificate SHA-1 thumbprint) Header Parameter is a
> base64url-encoded SHA-1 thumbprint (a.k.a. digest) of the DER
> encoding of the X.509 certificate [RFC5280] corresponding to the key
> used to digitally sign the JWS.  Note that certificate thumbprints
> are also sometimes known as certificate fingerprints.  Use of this
> Header Parameter is OPTIONAL.

Source: RFC7515 — https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7515#section-4.1.7

Comment: Hi @evilSnobu, Thank for the info. However i am still not able to figure out how Microsoft  could get the values published in "x5t" listed [here](https://login.botframework.com/v1/.well-known/keys). If i copy the value of "x5c" at any online X.509 decoder, they doesn't match with the processed value from certificate's hash.

Answer (score 0):

In Powershell 7.x, this goes like this. Important: Do **not** use the thumbprint from the cert to calculate x5t but instead do it like below,

```
$CertThumbPrint = '<Thumbprint of your cert with private key, stored in machine/Personal'
$CertificatePath = "cert:\localmachine\my\$CertThumbPrint" #<Add the Certificate Path Including Thumbprint here e.g. cert:\currentuser\my\6C1EE1A11F57F2495B57A567211220E0ADD72DC1 >#
$Cert = Get-Item -Path $CertificatePath

# *** use this (and comment the above line) if you want to load the cert from a pfx file instead of getting it from the machine cert store
#$cert = New-Object System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2((join-path -path $PSScriptRoot -ChildPath "ExtractContractsFrom-ITSystemMBX.pfx"),"<PFX password>")

$CertificateBase64Hash = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String($cert.GetCertHash())

# Use the CertificateBase64Hash and replace/strip to match web encoding of base64
$x5t = $CertificateBase64Hash -replace '\+','-' -replace '/','_' -replace '='
```

Answer (score 0):

When I used the below command, it was not generating the correct fingerprint because my **default fingerprint output** was **SHA256** and not **SHA1**.

```
echo $(openssl x509 -in your.cert.pem -fingerprint -noout) | sed 's/SHA1 Fingerprint=//g' | sed 's/://g' | xxd -r -ps | base64
```

So I updated the command to output fingerprint specifically in **SHA1** as below, and it worked. Same command also worked for **.crt** file format of certificate:

```
echo $(openssl x509 -in your.cert.pem -fingerprint -sha1 -noout) | sed 's/SHA1 Fingerprint=//g' | sed 's/://g' | xxd -r -ps | base64
```

Another way to get the fingerprint for Microsoft Azure is to utilize the thumbprint generated after uploading of the certificate. Use the thumbprint column value to generate it.
[image]

```
echo "THUMBRINT COLUMN VALUE" |xxd -r -p| openssl enc -a
```

**OR**

```
echo "THUMBRINT COLUMN VALUE" |xxd -r -p| base64
```

Answer (score 0):

This Python code will output the correct value and you can put it into any online compiler:

```
import base64
import binascii

hash_hex = "CERT_THUMBPRINT"
hash_bytes = binascii.unhexlify(hash_hex)
hash_base64url = base64.urlsafe_b64encode(hash_bytes).rstrip(b'=').decode('utf-8')

print(hash_base64url)
```